# k-mean without label

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering, k-means

i m try to apply k-means with Python 3 to my dataset (Amazon review)  for classify similar user (from review).

I just have a TF and TF-IDF matrix (and i have a row(user) and columns(words) value in distinct csv file)
[image]

I m starting with sklearn from this sketch

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-plot-document-clustering-py

but in my case i don't have label or category, and i don't understand how k-means can cluster different items from this matrix TD-IDF.

1. How can I group similar words from my dataset, from the matrix
   without having any information?
2. How do I show these n-clusters in the chart?
3. And how do I show the similar words of this cluster, if I do not
   have any information (like label or category)?

For now this is my code :

```
k = 5
km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=5)
km.fit(Y) ##Y is my TD-IDF matrix

original_centroids = svd.inverse_transform(km.cluster_centers_)
print(original_centroids.shape) 
for i in range(original_centroids.shape[0]):
original_centroids[i] = np.array([x for x in original_centroids[i]])
svd_centroids = original_centroids.argsort()[:, ::-1]
```

i would like have a set like this(with similar word near)

[image]

I m very lost, because i m new in this word.

Comment: There is no question...

Comment: the question is...how to apply k-means without the label. I edit the question

Comment: The question doesn't make sense; k-means is an unsupervised technique and by nature has nothing to do with labels

Comment: maybe I have to reformulate the question. Unfortunately I saw only this example and I saw these labels and maybe I was too tied to this particular. @SeanOwen My question was more specific than k-means, because I was trying to catalog users in different groups, but I understand how it is possible (it seems too magical) how I can divide them without knowing anything except the TD-IDF matrix and print with that example of related topics. This is why I tied myself to those labels.. I will edit the question.

Comment: @theantomc are you trying to cluster words or users. In the edit you proposed it says you are trying to cluster words, for which k-means would be the wrong method but if it's user what you are trying to cluster then this question could be edited to reflect that intention.

Comment: i m try to cluster word, and the output i think will be a list of similar word for similar topic

Comment: @theantomc then the approach is erroneous and for that reason I'm going to vote to keep the question closed. If your intention is to cluster word meanings then you should look for approaches like word embeddings. If you want to cluster documents or users in your case, then k-means becomes a good option as each word becomes a feature to be measured for a distance. Check out this article about word embeddings https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/03/11/word-is-worth-a-thousand-vectors/ it might help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Wacax unfortunatly I need use k-means for requirements. I see many example like my case, but have different Tf-idf, because starting from dataset. I m starting from tf-idf matrix, so missing vocabulary

Comment: If you don't have the vocabulary, how do you expect an algorithm to come up with words?!?

Answer (score 1):

K-means does not use labels.

The example that you looked at uses labels to compare the clusters to the labels. That part obviously requires labels; but that is not part of k-means.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. So i don't understand how to classification this topics... Because i don't how to divided in groups similar topics. Because in example use " terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()" for take "names" and cluster to different topics... In my case, just with TF-IDF i have just a division, but i don't know the topic... sorry this question that could be stupid, i m trying to understand

Comment: K-means does not produce a topic. It produces center vectors. You'll have to make these "topics" yourself. But what is a "topic" anyway? That is subjective.

Comment: Because i dont cover how to do with this "topic"

Comment: Nor do I. Because it's undefined. *You* have to define what a topic is. K-means doesn't use topics, it uses means.

Comment: For me the topic, is a different cluster. In this way i think that if I have a "topic car" i see just word related to the car... I think that is the way of the cluster

Comment: Well, for k-means a cluster is a mean, not the word "car". If *you* want something different, then you'll need to write a program to compute what *you* expect. K-means is expected to give means.

Comment: I did not want to create problems, I just wanted to apply the k-means to my example. Unfortunately, my dataset started from the matrix, having only that example on the scikit learn I was based on that. I have also looked for other similar applications, but the dataset is always different and even the operations seem different.